# sectioning / document hierarchy issue / start new root / move section up one level

Tags: sectioning, chapters, parts

Sorry for the bad title, but couldn't come up with something better. I have a problem with the section-hierarchy of my latex document:

This is my document structure:

```
\begin{document}

[...]

\part{ Conclusion}
\chapter{Conclusion and Future Work}
\section{Summary}
\section{Answers to Research Questions}
\section{Future Work}
\backmatter
\listoffigures 
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\printindex
\printglossaries
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{thesis}
\chapter{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{document}
```

The following picture shows the hierarchy, after opening the PDF in adobe acrobat:

[image]

As you can see, everything starting from *List of Figures* is under the *Conclusion* chapter. However, I would like to have it on the same level as *Conclusion*.

Interestingly, in the table of contents it is printed as I would like to see it also on the document hierarchy above (EDIT: I think I came to a wrong conclusion here. These sections (i.e., *List of Figures*, etc.) are not numbered. In fact they still might be sectioned under the *Conclusion* part):

[image]

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: yep. see my answer.

Comment: I've marked as possible duplicate because I've seen your answer and cannot appreciate what's new in your question/answer from what's in [Move section out of part](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73996/1952). But, of course, it's just my opinion.

Comment: i agree, however, maybe my question makes it easier to retrieve the solution for people having the same issue in future. after conducting an initial search, i did not find the other stackoverflow-question, because it does not contain the keywords, i was looking for. so maybe at least in this way, this question can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the following did the trick (source: [Move section out of part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73996/move-section-out-of-part)):

```
\usepackage{bookmark}
[...]
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
```

Use `\bookmarksetup{startatroot}` where you want to start a new root. In my case right after `\backmatter`:

```
\begin{document}

[...]

\part{ Conclusion}
\chapter{Conclusion and Future Work}
\section{Summary}
\section{Answers to Research Questions}
\section{Future Work}
\backmatter
\bookmarksetup{startatroot}
\listoffigures 
\listoftables
\listofalgorithms
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Algorithms}
\printindex
\printglossaries
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{thesis}
\chapter{Curriculum Vitae}
\end{document}
```

Result looks like:

[image]

Table of Contents looks like before:

[image]